# Issue with comparison with floating point

Tags: c, floating-point

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    float a = 0.7;
    if(a<0.7)
        printf("C");
    else
        printf("c++");
}
```

I was going through a text book test your c skills by an Indian author. I found this question in a floating point problems chapter. I am comparing `(0.7<0.7)` which is false. So why is the output `c` and not `c++`.

Comment: Do you know how [IEEE floating point math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) works? Hint: What type is `0.7` by default? What single keyword would you change to make this code produce C++?

Comment: I am trying to learn the answer to your first question. 0.7 is double is default which I just came to know, so every other float constant are treated as `double`. I don't know the answer to your last question. I have one of my own question so what is the default type of non floating numbers is it `int`?

Comment: `7` is an `int`, `0.7` is a `double`. When comparing a `double` to a `float` you may get *strange* results because [floating point math can be weird](https://floating-point-gui.de).

Comment: "I am comparing (0.7<0.7)" --> No you are comparing `(0.7f<0.7)`

Comment: Try `printf("%a %a\n", 0.7f, 0.7);` for more insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation:
0.7 is double constant (Default). Its binary value is
written in 64 bit.
Binary value of 0.7 = (0.1011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011
0011 0011 0011 0011 0011)
Now here variable a is a floating-point variable while
0.7 is double constant. So variable a will contain only
32 bit value i.e.

```
a = 0.1011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 
while
0.7 = 0.1011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011
0011 0011....
```

It is obvious a < 0.7

Comment: Binary value of 0.7f = (0.1011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011).  Other 8 bits of the 32 are for exponent and sign.